# Drinking Camel Urine?

Tags: halal-haram, sunnah

I have read about hadith where the prophet pbuh advised drinking camel urine for medication. Is this true? I mean, its urine,which is a liquid that contains toxins being expelled from the body. I really don't think the prophet would have advised something like this, and in general modern science supports the fact that any kind of urine is harmful for consumption. Here's the hadith I'm taking about:

> Narrated Abu Qilaba: "Anas said, "Some people of 'Ukl or 'Uraina tribe came to Medina and its climate did not suit them. So the Prophet ordered them to go to the herd of (Milch) camels and to drink their milk and urine (as a medicine). So they went as directed and after they became healthy, they killed the shepherd of the Prophet and drove away all the camels. The news reached the Prophet early in the morning and he sent (men) in their pursuit and they were captured and brought at noon. He then ordered to cut their hands and feet (and it was done), and their eyes were branded with heated pieces of iron, They were put in 'Al-Harra' and when they asked for water, no water was given to them." Abu Qilaba said, "Those people committed theft and murder, became infidels after embracing Islam and fought against Allah and His Apostle .  (Sahih Bukhari, Ablutions (Wudu'), Volume 1, Book 4, Number 234)"

Comment: The Hadith is Sahih according to Bukhari's standard, and that is the answer to your main question. Interpretations vary regarding whether this makes camel urine pure and usable as medication. The Hanafis and Shafis do not consider it pure nor lawful to consume, and say that the prescription was specific to the people to whom it was instructed, and they suffered from a disease to which they had no other available cure.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you mean is the hadith true? Or is it about the use of camel urine? Or about camel urine being a medication? To make a general statement that camel urine is not scientifically accepted is not entirely accurate (see this [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22922085) for example).

Comment: In islam  there is a conceptt of abbrogation - this hadith is abrogated